# How can I mount a filesystem, mapping userids?

Tags: mount, ext4

I can successfully mount an ext4 partition, the problem is that all the files on the partition are owned by the user with userid 1000. On one machine, my userid is 1000, but on another it's 1010. My username is the same on both machines, but I realise that the filesystem stores userids, not usernames.

I could correct the file ownership with something like the following:

```
find /mnt/example -exec chown -h 1010 {} \;
```

But then I would have to correct the file ownerships again back to 1000 when I mount this external drive on another machine.

What I would like is to give `mount` an option saying map userid 1000 to 1010, so that I don't have to actually modify any files. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38323/33055

Comment: I search for this question a year and a half later, found this, wanted to upvote, only to discover that I asked this question myself!

Comment: You can still make it a favourite, even if you can't upvote :-O

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take a look at the [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/) package. bindfs is a FUSE filesystem that allows for various manipulations of file permissions, file ownership etc. on top of existing file systems.

You are looking specifically for the [--map option](http://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html) of bindfs:

```
--map=user1/user2:@group1/@group2:..., -o map=...
    Given a mapping user1/user2, all files owned by user1 are shown as owned by user2. When user2 creates files, they are chowned to user1 in the underlying directory. When files are chowned to user2, they are chowned to user1 in the underlying directory. Works similarly for groups.

    A single user or group may appear no more than once on the left and once on the right of a slash in the list of mappings. Currently, the options --force-user, --force-group, --mirror, --create-for-*, --chown-* and --chgrp-* override the corresponding behavior of this option.

    Requires mounting as root.
```

So to map your files with user id 1001 in `/mnt/wrong` to `/mnt/correct` with user id 1234, run this command:

```
sudo bindfs --map=1001/1234 /mnt/wrong /mnt/correct
```

Comment: I'm getting `fuse: unknown option \`--map=1004/1002'` on my Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS server. I wonder if my version of bindfs or fuse is outdated...

Comment: You have to change `1004/1002` to your user IDs. You can find them using `id -u username`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a kernel >5.12 and on a supported filesystem (ext4 should be fine, but BTRFS support wasn't added until 5.15), you can use the [idmapping](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.12#ID_mapping_in_mounts) in mounts feature. You will need to use the [mount-idmapped](https://github.com/brauner/mount-idmapped) program until you have a util-linux new enough to support the [`X-mount.idmap`](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/pull/1661) feature for `mount`.

A simple example is:
Using `mount-idmapped`
When on the machine where your uid is 1010, you could use the following command:
`mount-idmapped --map-mount b:1000:1010:1 /mnt/example /mnt/example`

There are some caveats, like you can't map two host uids to the same target uid. So bindfs is a more general solution, but this should work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bindfs](http://bindfs.org). It can bind the filesystem to some other mountpoint with different uid/gid. However I think I would just change the uid so it is the same on both systems.