# Debian/dpkg handle group id collision

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, group

In my network there is a special user group with the ID `101`. Unfortunatelly, Debian wants to use the ID `101` for the group `systemd-journal`.

Since it exists only locally, I assigned `systemd-journal` the group ID `99` and so I was able to have our special user group `101`. I know this is asking for trouble, but the alternative is using a distro where group ID `101` is not used by the OS.

Every time something/-one calls `dpkg-reconfigure systemd` there is an error, b/c `dpkg` is unhappy about the GID change. In these cases I switch the GID of `systemd-journal` back to `101`, do the reconfigure and then switch it to `99` again.

This is so much manual work, I was wondering: How can I make dpkg accept the GID change of `systemd-journal` to 99? Can I make it ignore this problem?

Comment: Alternatively: You maybe able to map the GID of the network share to a different (reserved) number, when you mount it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor When mounting a share I can do a gid mapping of an arbitrary id to another arbitrary id? Will this leave other group-ownerships intact? How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You should reserve a GID for it. However I am not the person to ask, as I have only seen it in the manual, but not done it, or remember where in the manuals. (I would start with looking at the mount manual).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I did before writing my comment. It's not there. I only thing I was able to find quickly is that with NFS4 I can set the GID of the nobody group when mounting a share. I'd rather not overload the nobody group.

Comment: This may help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158695/4778

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor nice! i'll try bindfs. I think this can solve my actual problem. Thanks! I'd still like my question answered. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different gid for `systemd-journal`, but it has to be in the system group range, which by default is 100–999. You *could* extend the range to include 99, by editing [`adduser.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/adduser.conf.5), but that would be a bad idea because [groups 0–99 are allocated statically](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#uid-and-gid-classes).

So you can’t easily make 99 acceptable as a gid for `systemd-journal`, but you can use another gid such as 999. Another approach could be to configure `adduser.conf` to specify a system range which is safe on your network, say 200–999, before the first system group is created.