# How to fix a mount error with -o options?

Tags: linux, mount

centos

I'm able to do this

```
$ mkdir /mnt/jenkins_master
$ mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/jenkins_master
```

However, the mounted files have the wrong `user:group` and doing the following takes a loonnnnggg time

```
$ chown -R jenkins:jenkins /mnt/jenkins_master
```

So I'm trying this instead, and getting the subsequent error

```
$ mount -o umask=0022,gid=jenkins,uid=jenkins /dev/xvdf /mnt/jenkins_master
mount: /mnt/jenkins_master: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

The volume is `ext4` and adding the `mount -t ext4 ...` option does not help.

What's the fix?

Comment: I think `gid=` and `uid=` are not valid mount options for ext4. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158678/108618) maybe (and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1242432/432690)).

Comment: I have a CentOS (AWS-optimized) image, and `bindfs` is not loaded. Interestingly enough, `yum install bindfs` says it cannot find the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are **not available** for ext* filesystems. Check the man page for [mount(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). these options are only valid with filesystems like tmpfs, fat, adfs ...

Comment: Thanks! So what is a safe option to convert an ext4 files system to so I can use the uid and gid options? The volume will be mounted on CentOS box

Comment: The root file system is ext4 in the CentOS box I want to mount the volume to

Comment: Just use the basic chown command and get your result. if you wan more speed you can try to use direclty find (find <path>/* | xargs chown <user>:<group>)

Comment: I am doing the `chown` command, but like I said, it takes a looonnnnng time. I want to change ownership of the WHOLE directory tree, hence my post.